# how to be ensure the google speech api return values - java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i try to write a code for android app that take a string that returned from google speech api and use it to send to other object "levenshte.testLevenshteindistance", within same thread.

the problem i can't make it to be synchronize work!
i mean my code call the object before the google speech api return value "depended on internet  speed"?!

```
ublic class MainActivity extends Activity {


public ListView sList;
ArrayList<String> names;
int sfound;
mp3Player mp3Player;    
Levenshteindistance levenshte;

public static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    voiceinputbuttons();
    starVoiceRecognation();
}


private void starVoiceRecognation() {
      Thread timer = new Thread(){           
        public void run(){
                new VoiceRecognizer().execute();

            //names is an ArrayList returnd by google speech api

                sfound=levenshte.testLevenshteindistance(names.get(0).toString());

        }
      };timer.start(); 
}


public void voiceinputbuttons() {
    sList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //default value if create mp3player before set sName or rName or actionNumbe
     names=null;
     levenshte = new Levenshteindistance();

}


public void informationMenu() {
    startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.INFOSCREEN"));
    }


public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speech recognition demo");
    try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    }

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // i want the timer thread wait until assign a value to  this name variable

        names = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            if (names.contains("information")) {
                informationMenu();
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private class VoiceRecognizer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url1) {

        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

        return null;
        }

}


}
```

i want be sure that the names not null when call the levenshte.testLevenshteindistance(names.get(0).toString());

Answer (score 2):

You're set up wrong for this.  You don't start voice recognition in a task and assume it will be over by the time some timer runs.  Voice recognition takes time, and it will call you back in onActivityResult when its done.  You should be starting your new activity there.

In addition, the voice recognition activity may return null on error.  I'd do a null check anyway, just to make sure.

Comment: sorry, i need more explain!

Comment: How i can make it inside the doInBackground function ?

Comment: YOu don't.  Voice recognition is handled by another app.  YOu call startActivity to start it, and when its done it will call onActivityResult.